# Mocking abstract classes interfaces in c#

Tags: c#, moq

I have the following type hierarchy in my code, this follows RuleEngine Design pattern and my code is as below,

Interface:

```
public interface IRuleContext<T>
{}
```

Concrete:
myDto is the parameter type i am passing

```
public class concreteContext : IRuleContext<myDto>
{
    public concreteContext(myDto>){}
}
```

interface:

```
public interface IRule<T>
{}
```

Concrete type implementing IRuleChain

```
public class RuleChain<T> : IRuleChain<T>{}

public interface IRuleChain<T> { Use(); Build();}

public abstract class Rule<T> : IRule<T>
{ Use<TRule>{};   Build(); }
```

In my Unit test-case I want to do Mocking of above rules, instead of calling as below,

```
new RuleChain<myContext>().Use<IsWhiteRule>().Use<IsBlackRule>();
```

I want to mock above types.

This is the repo to the above code base, https://github.com/lutticoelho/RulesChain

Comment: what effort have you made to using moq?

Comment: You've stated an *objective* ("I want to mock..."). You haven't stated/shown what *problem* you're having achieving that objective. We assume you're at least capable of finding and reading documentation, tutorials or getting started guides, so what help are you asking for here?

Comment: Hi Daniel, This is what I am trying to pass to the Rule<T>                                          
    var myMoc = new Mock<Rule<isWhiteRule>>();                                
    myMoc.Setup(m => m.Run<isWhiteRule>()).Returns(myreturnObj);    Now When I am trying to call the rule on I am expecting some object to be returned. Run() is what I am trying to Mock here.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I tried using NSubstitute, Below is the code                     
    `IRule<DummyContext> rc = Substitute.For<IRule<DummyContext>>();
    rc.When(x => x.Run(context).Returns(context)); `     So basically when call is made to Run() it should return the same object.  I am mocking the actual implementation with dummydata.  Please correct me in case i am passing wrong generic type.